# C++: How do unordered containers prevent duplications?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-map, unordered-set

Let's take unordered_set for example.
The default predicate for determining if two elements are equal is `std::equal_to<T>(t1,t2)`,
which is simply `t1==t2`.
Now lets suppose that for this T type I've implemented `operator==()` so that not all member variables are part of this comparison, i.e two different T elements t1,t2 can be equal on comparison.

If the underlying hashtable calculates a different hash for each of these t1 and t2, when does it even perform the `t1==t2` check for duplication of keys? and if there are more checks, how does it stay constant-time on average?

Comment: If two elements are equal, their hashes MUST be equal.  It's possible to have 2 objects with the same hash that are not equal.  It's not possible with a proper hash to have 2 objects that are equal yet have different hashes.

Comment: So for an object with member variables a, b and c, but only a and b are used for equality, then the hash should only use a and b.  If x and y objects use `(x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b) || (x.a == y.b && x.b == y.a)` (a criss-cross equality), then the hash had better figure out a way to come up with the same hash for both situations.

Comment: @Eljay So i have to provide unordered containers with a different hash calculation whenever i override operator==()  ?

Comment: @ShookiMatzliah It doesn't.  _You_ are responsible for implementing an appropriate `std::hash` specialization based on your class's logic.

Comment: If you are using your object in a container that needs a hasher, you are obligated to provide the hasher for your class objects.  q.v. [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).  Unless you are using one of the `std` objects that C++ already provides a hasher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key point that you're missing is that you supply two functors to the unordered container, and they have to work together.

There's the hash function, which calculates a number from an object.

There's a comparison function, which compares two objects for "equivalence".

As @Eljay said in his comment, for two objects that compare "equivalent" (the comparison function returns `true`), the hash function *must* return the same value.

If your functions do not provide this guarantee, then the containers will not work correctly.

#### Relatively good reference (though not authoritative)

> [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set): Meets the requirements of UnorderedAssociativeContainer.
> [UnorderedAssociativeContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer): are parameterized by Key/Hash/Pred.
> With the requriement:
> * If two Keys are equal according to Pred.
> * Hash must return the same value for both keys.

Answer (score 1):

> If the underlying hashtable calculates a different hash for each of these t1 and t2, when does it even perform the t1==t2 check for duplication of keys?

When the hash function causes newly inserted element to be placed into a non-empty bucket. Comparison will be made between pre-existing elements in that bucket to ensure uniqueness.

> how does it stay constant-time on average?

By assuming that the hash function distributes random keys into the buckets evenly, and by increasing the number of buckets as the number of elements grows.

> how could std::hash know how i implement openrator==()

Whoever writes the specialisation of std::hash for your class must know how you implement operator==.

The hash function must produce same hash for all elements that compare equal. If it doesn't, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Standard refs: [[unord.req]](https://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req), [[defns.required.behavior]](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.required.behavior)

Answer (score 1):

The unordered associateive containers require that any two keys that compare equal also have the same hash.  From [[unord.req]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unord.req#5):

> The container's object of type `Hash` — denoted by `hash` — is called the hash function of the container. The container's object of type `Pred` — denoted by `pred` — is called the key equality predicate of the container.
>
> Two values `k1` and `k2` are considered equivalent if the container's key equality predicate `pred(k1, k2)` is valid and returns `true` when passed those values. If `k1` and `k2` are equivalent, the container's hash function shall return the same value for both.

Your `operator==` and `std::hash` implementations must be consistent.  If they are not then you have not fulfilled the prerequisites required to use your class as the key in an unordered associative container.